# Django RestFramework: two way ForeignKey relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There are two models Parent and Children.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    children = ?

class Children(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent = ?
```

If we need the children instances to have parent as link to model Parent we can use ForeignKey in Children and vice versa.

If parent A has children B and C and we want A to have ids of children B and C and children B and C to have id of parent A.
i.e. A.children = (B.id, C.id) and B.parent = A.id, C.parent = A.id.

How can we achieve this?

```
parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

can this be used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a `Child` instance has exactly one parent a `ForeignKey` field to the parent model is the correct relation. Your example looks fine to me except that the convention is that model names are singular rather than plural - `class Child(models.Model):` rather than `class Children(models.model):`.

Comment: Using ForeignKey and related name, would both instances (Parent A and child B) have a reference to each other i.e. fields 'parent' for Child and 'children' for Parent?

Comment: In the database, the information is stored only on the child record. But using the Django API, both instances have a reference. The field for `Parent` instances will be a manager named using the `related_name` attribute of the `ForeignKey` field, or `child_set` if you don't name it, so you'd fetch all with `child_set.all()` or do further selection with `child_set.filter(...)` etc.